# dblclick handler not registered by angular's test suite

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I have an Angular 4 component that listens to a `dblclick` event. This works fine in the browser:

**acticle.component.html**

```
<div (dblclick)="openArticle()">
    <!-- stuff -->
</div>
```

**acticle.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector   : 'app-article',
    templateUrl: 'article.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['article.component.scss'],
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {

    // stuff

    openArticle(): void {
      // simplified code
      this.openArticleInCs();            
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to test if the double click properly executes what happens inside `openArticle()`, like so:

```
describe('Component: ArticleComponent', () => {

    // some variable declarations here

    beforeEach(() => {

        // some variable definitions here

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [/* some declarations here */],
            imports: [/* some modules here */],
            providers: [/* some providers here */]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ArticleFactoryComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ArticleComponent));
        el = de.nativeElement;
        articleComponent = de.injector.get(ArticleComponent);
    });

    it('should open an article in CS on double click', () => {
        articleComponent.openArticleInCue = jasmine.createSpy('openArticleInCue').and.returnValue(undefined);
        articleComponent.openArticleInCs = jasmine.createSpy('openArticleInCs').and.returnValue(undefined);
        de.triggerEventHandler("dblclick", new MouseEvent("dblclick"));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(articleComponent.openArticleInCs).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

But the tests fail at

```
expect(articleComponent.openArticleInCs).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Using the debugger I can see that `triggerEventHandler` works and inside that function Angular iterates though the defined event handlers for this component. However, the event handlers are empty! So it seems to me Angular's test suite does not understand that I have a `dblclick` handler there (if i am not mistaken on my presumption that is).

Comment: DId my answer help?